# Where to find exported GameKit log files?

Tags: logging, gamekit

On iOS you can export GameKit log files from within the settings app. However it fails to tell you where to find these log files. You cannot view them from Xcode->devices either.

Answer (score 9):

I finally found this information. Hope it helps!

#### Getting Crash Logs Without Xcode

After plugging in the device, and syncing with iTunes, crash logs can be found in the following locations, depending on the platform:

Crash log locations

- Mac OS X:
  ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/<DEVICE_NAME>
- Windows XP:
  C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Apple Computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\<DEVICE_NAME>
- Windows Vista or 7:
  C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\<DEVICE_NAME>

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the logs from the iOS simulator, found them using find in the terminal ...

```
find -x / -name GameKit-Log*
```